# How to use casting in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a long field which it's name is `pan`. I want to have a query which casts this field to string, so that I can find all the pans starting with `6273` or end with `7985` or containing `8110`.

Comment: Either store a copy as a string or use scripted fields. :)

Comment: Thanks @EvaldasBuinauskas just see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer, just use :

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": {
            "filtered": {
               "query": {
                  "match_all": {}
               },
               "filter": {
                  "script": {
                     "script": "doc['pan'].value.toString().matches('.*88.*');"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```